# Xcode Webview or HttpRequest not Working, after many times tried

Tags: xcode, webview, httprequest

I work on a hybrid based Xcode application, processing requirement app request to many times to server, this is same time WebView content loading, same times HttpRequest with POST, any time after many requests, web will or `httpRequest` not more working, by `HttpRequest` return always null and by WebView content not more load (blank screen), for that I become any errors on console or by catch, if I remove app from device and install again, is all work perfectly again.

My HttpRequest:

```
NSString * stringURLComplete = `http://mydomain.c`
NSMutableURLRequest *req = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:stringURLComplete]];
[req setValue:@"gzip" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept-Encoding"];
[req setHTTPBody:[strData dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[req setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
NSError         * err = nil;
NSURLResponse   * response = nil;
NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:req returningResponse:&response error:&err];
NSDictionary *resulta = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
NSArray *list = [resulta objectForKey:@"data"];
return list;
```

Comment: Where is the `WebView` request? And this is very old code .. from where you got it. See some tutorials on google for `"HTTP request in objective - c"`.

Comment: I think this problem not via Request, ist another, while after reinstall app work all without problem. but after any times not more working!, may be app blocked from system automatically ?